# Flip <canvas> (rotate 180deg) after being published on page

Tags: html, canvas

I'm trying to rotate a canvas element AFTER it's been appended to the DOM.
Canvas is 600x50 and this is the code at hand:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[2];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.translate(300, 25); // rotate @ center

ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI/180);
```

which isn't accomplishing the task. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to rotate from landscape to portrait? (if yes, change the width and height)
What's the "angle" variable?

Comment: Not exactly, just flip it vertically.. see this screenshot: http://i42.tinypic.com/71jpqa.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Dug around and found this working solution;

```
context.scale(1,-1); //flip vertically 
context.translate(0,-height); //move beneath original position
```

works wonders!

Comment: will this work for bit map images too? I am having some trouble there.. =/

Comment: If you are allowed to use CSS3, you might be able to use a similar CSS transformation.