# HTML5 Mirroring webcam canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webcam, webcam-capture

I'm trying to take a webcam feed - (landscape format), cut out the middle bit (portrait format) and have it render to a canvas so that it fills the screen portrait 1080px by 1920px (for this I scale the bit I cut out by 3.8). I then need to flip this canvas so the image is mirrored. I've succeeded in cutting out the middle bit, and rendering this to the canvas... I just cant figure out how to flip it.

**Edit**

Thank you to all the people who have pointed me at context.scale(-1, 1) - my problem is, I'm already using scale... I think my issues are to do with saving the context, but everything I try has failed to work?

```
<script>
       // Put event listeners into place
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
                context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
                video = document.getElementById("video"),
                videoObj = { 
                    video: {
                        mandatory: {
                            minWidth: 1280,
                            minHeight: 720,
                            /*Added by Chad*/
                            maxWidth: 1280,
                            maxHeight: 720
                        }
                    }
                },
                errBack = function(error) {
                    console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
                };

            // Put video listeners into place
            if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
                navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                    video.src = stream;
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
                navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            } else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
                navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            }

            /*
                video : video source tag
                320,0 : the shift coords
                320,180 : the canvas size
                0,0 : no shift in the canvas
                640,360 : important ! it’s the native resolution of video source
            */
            context.scale(3.8,3.8);

            function loop(){
               context.drawImage(video, 450, 0, 1080, 1920, 0, 0, 720, 1280);
               setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30);
            }

            loop();


        }, false);
</script> 


    <video id="video" height="1080" width="1920" autoplay></video>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="1920" width="1080"></canvas>


// Put event listeners into place
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        video = document.getElementById("video"),
        videoObj = { 
            video: {
                mandatory: {
                    minWidth: 1280,
                    minHeight: 720,
                    /*Added by Chad*/
                    maxWidth: 1280,
                    maxHeight: 720
                }
            }
        },
        errBack = function(error) {
            console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
        };

    // Put video listeners into place
    if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
        navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
            video.src = stream;
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    } else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    }

    /*
        video : video source tag
        320,0 : the shift coords
        320,180 : the canvas size
        0,0 : no shift in the canvas
        640,360 : important ! it’s the native resolution of video source
    */




    context.scale(-3.8,3.8);
    context.translate(-720,0);
    function loop(){
       context.drawImage(video, 450, 0, 1080, 1920, 0, 0, 720, 1280);
       setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30);
    }

    loop();


}, false);
```

Comment: There was a similar [question about flipping context vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634456/flip-canvas-rotate-180deg-after-being-published-on-page), hopefully it can help.

Comment: Also, there's [a nice tutorial on mirroring canvas](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mirror-transform-tutorial/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't do the crop using the `ctx.scale` and `ctx.translate` methods.

Instead, on load of your video, calculate the cropping positions and then in the call of your drawing loop, apply those calculated positions.

When done, it's easy to apply the `context.scale(-1, 1);` as proposed by @Mahout.
Note that you'll also need to `context.translate(canvas.width, 0);` before applying the `scale()`.

I refactored your code because the way you were requesting the video mandatories is [out of date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28911694/3702797) (as is chrome about it).

I changed your loop too, in order to call it only when the video has loaded, no need to try to draw anything that doesn't exists yet, and I changed your `setTimeout` with the [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) method, which fires approximatly at 30fps.

```js
// Put event listeners into place
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        // we don't need to append the video to the document
        video = document.createElement("video"),
        videoObj = 
        navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia ? // our browser is up to date with specs ?
        { 
        video: {
            width: { min: 1280,  max: 1280 },
            height: { min: 720,  max: 720 },
            require: ['width', 'height']
            }
        }:
        {
        video: {
            mandatory: {
                minWidth: 1280,
                minHeight: 720,
                maxWidth: 1280,
                maxHeight: 720
            }
        }
    },
    errBack = function(error) {
        console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
    };
    // create a crop object that will be calculated on load of the video
    var crop;
    // create a variable that will enable us to stop the loop.
    var raf;
    
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
    // Put video listeners into place
        navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.onplaying = function(){
                var croppedWidth = ( Math.min(video.videoHeight, canvas.height) / Math.max(video.videoHeight,canvas.height)) * Math.min(video.videoWidth, canvas.width),
                croppedX = ( video.videoWidth - croppedWidth) / 2;
                crop = {w:croppedWidth, h:video.videoHeight, x:croppedX, y:0};
                // call our loop only when the video is playing
                raf = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
                };
            video.onpause = function(){
                // stop the loop
                cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
                }
            video.play();
        }, errBack);

    function loop(){
       context.drawImage(video, crop.x, crop.y, crop.w, crop.h, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
       raf = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
// now that our video is drawn correctly, we can do...
context.translate(canvas.width, 0);
context.scale(-1,1);

}, false);
```

```css
body,html{margin:0}
canvas{ border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="1920" width="1080"></canvas>
```

[**jsfiddle** for chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/zcey2mmq/1)

Comment: Thanks Kalido - this is exactly what I needed! :) Also, thank you for the explanation - its given me a better understanding of canvas.

Answer (score 1):

For flipping horizontally you can use `context.scale(-1, 1);`.

From http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mirror-transform-tutorial/

**EDIT**

As a last resort, this CSS could be used

```
#canvas {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

If required, this could all be applied dynamically with javascript.  Untested but should hopefully work!

Comment: Hi Sam, Yep - I read about that... the problem I have is that I'm already using scale...

Comment: Woops didn't see this. In which case just use `context.scale(-3.8,3.8);` instead of the original call.

Comment: Hi Sam, I tried that - and it didnt work... so I read I had to multiply the width by -1... but that caused it to render off screen

Comment: @Rob ofcourse it renders off screen because scale multiplies each point x,y values by the values given (x * -1, y * 1). in your case seems that you can solve this by translating by image width `context.scale(-1, 1);context.translate(-720,0)`

Comment: @user2786485 - thanks. I tried that, and now get half the frame of video - and its kinda squished

Comment: where are you doing the scale/translate? inside the function or outside?

Comment: Outside  - I'll update my question with the revised code

Comment: You could try moving it inside the function and then at the end of each function call `context.restore()` - worth a try, perhaps.

Comment: Hi Mahout - thanks, unfortunately, I need to capture the canvas later on - so a css transform won't work here.

Comment: I think you should try to adjust the `drawImage` parameters to fit your needs. notice in the canvas parameters, height is greater than width, but in `drawImage` it is the opposite.

Comment: also note that `context.drawImage(video, 450, 0, 1080, 1920, 0, 0, 720, 1280);` means: `clipX = 450; clipY = 0; clipWidth = 1080; clipHeight = 1920; x = 0; y = 0; width=720; height=1280;` maybe clipX is cutting your image

Answer (score 0):

Quick Answer (Tried and Tested):

```
let context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
context.translate(width, 0)
context.scale(-1, 1)
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height)
```