How to mirror/flip horizantally web cam video recording in JS?
I want to record the web came video. I am able to record the normal web cam video. But I want video to be mirrored/ flipped horizantally. How can I do it?
Here is my code:
window.navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
        video: {
            width: { ideal: 1920 },
            height: { ideal: 1080 },
            frameRate: 30,
        },
    })
    .then((stream) => {
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        const blobParts = [];
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
            blobParts.push(event.data);
        });
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
            const blob = new Blob(blobParts);
            console.log(blob);
        });

        mediaRecorder.start();
        setTimeout(() => mediaRecorder.stop(), 10000);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

Thanks in advance!

@Yogi I know for the display, it can be done with the css. I want to flip the recorded data.

I'd suggest looking into using a canvas for manipulation of your stream. so, camera to canvas then canvas to media recorder. might be a good path...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104975/html5-mirroring-webcam-canvas
